# xmlhttprequest and php

Tags: php, xmlhttprequest

Here's a stupid question, don't laugh, I've been trying to figure this out but no luck, I guess I'm too tired. So there's an application sending data (image file as string) to a php script, sending it with `XMLHttpRequest.send(data)`. My question is how do I access this string in PHP to save it to a file?

EDIT `$_POST`, `$_GET` and `$_FILES` are all empty

Comment: $_REQUEST?(http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php).If all of the server variables are empty, the problem is likely in your javascript sending stuff. A snippet would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: Make sure you are sending a POST request (when you call the [`open`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-open-method) method)

Second: Since it looks like you are sending raw data, set an appropriate content type (with [`setRequestHeader`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader-method))

Third: You should be able to retrieve the data with [`$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php) or `file_get_contents("php://input");`.

Comment: I got it with `php://input`, thank you very much. Any idea how to parse the string if it starts with `data:image/png;base64...`, after this there are a bunch of random characters which I think it's the image itself. This string was generated with html5's `canvas.toDataURL()` I believe.

Comment: @slash197 you pass the not-so-random characters to `base64_decode()`, then save it to a file.